How would you say "travel broadens the mind" in Latin?
My knowledge of Latin is quite poor and would say "iter dilatat animum"? Is it even grammatically correct?

I agree with Tyler's suggestion that peregrinatio would be more appropriate than iter, unless you are referring to a specific trip (which does not appear to be the case).
That said, I would rather suggest the verbs augere or amplificare, which both essentially mean “extend, widen, increase, enlarge,” etc.
Thus, you would get: Peregrinatio mentem amplificat (or auget).

While I think peregrinatio is the preferred word (and agree re: augere/amplificare), a singular iter referring to itinera in general isn't out of with Latin aphoristic style.

@cmw I guess you're right, peregrinatio is a little boring actually, a little too straight. That said, the only aphorism abour itinera that immediately comes to mind is Seneca's old chestnut, longum iter est per praecepta … (nec mentem amplificat).

Yeah, I'm not sure it is ever attested in such a way, just that it isn't out of the realm of possibility grammatically. Time to spice it up a bit and go with something like iter novum, mens aucta.

Never in a million years would i believed to peak the interest of so many of you. And never would i believed how many ways are there to say a three word  idiom. Maybe the word "iter" is too catchy and short and therefore used by so many travel agencies and kind of stuck to my mind as the word to use. Also using animum instead of mens was purely to avoid a homonym to the english language and maybe an average person could deduct the meaning of the idiom without deep understanding of Latin.

Iter mentem dilatat is how I would translate that. Technically, your translation is grammatically correct, but I would use "mens" instead since I think that in this case it is more specific. Additionally, the direct object typically is put before the verb if the sentence is syntactically one clause and indicative.

So "mens" is the intellectual mind and "animum"  is more like the soul? Thank you for your input :)

@PyryJansson, your translation is fine. So is Mr. Simonson's. In this case animus and mens are near enough to synonyms. And word order in such a simple sentence makes no difference to meaning. I'd go with which sounds better, which has a better rythm, which has a better effect.

There are a lot of good options here, but in the vein of ars long, vita brevis, I'll keep it simpler and neutral to begin:

Iter novum, mens melior, "a new journey, a better mind."

I'm pulling mens melior from Quintilian, but other adjectives could also be used, like saepior or, my favorite of the three, amplius, the latter of which is seen with nouns like animus and spiritus.

There's a line from Horace (Epistles 1.11.27) that goes:

caelum non animum mutant qui trans mare currunt.
'Those who travel across the sea change the sky, not their mind/heart/spirit.'

It seems to me that this could be adopted into something serviceable – for example:

caelum atque animum mutant qui trans mare currunt.
'Those who travel across the sea change the sky and also their mind.'

Variations include:

non solum caelum sed [or sed etiam] animum… ('…not only the sky but also their mind')
cum caelum tum animum… ('…the sky as well as their mind')
et caelum et animum… ('…both the sky and their mind')


Alternative suggestion to stick to metre: Caelum animumque sibi mutat qui trans mare currit.

iter refers to a specific journey, and does not mean travelling around as an activity. The word you want is circumeo which means to tour or travel in a sight-seeing kind of way, or more technically peregrinatio which specifically means travelling.
The English idioms to "open the mind" or "broad minded" are not found in Latin. Probably the closest idea in Latin is the idea of variego which includes cultural variegation. So based on that your phrase could be expressed as:
Peregrinatio mentem variegat.
You could also write animum or pectorem instead of mentem. The closest Latin ideo to open mindedness is docilis which means teachable or receptive. So, you could write:
Peregrinatio animum dociliorem facit.
